# php unix to date not work correctly

Tags: php

i have a unix time 1410938094654
I want to convert this to date time format

```
 $dt = new DateTime('@1410938094654');
 $dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Tehran'));
 echo $dt->format('F j, Y, g:i a');
```

But the wrong time will returned

06-11-2000 00:30:54

correct time is GMT: Wednesday, September 17, 2014 7:14:54.654 AM

also my php.ini

```
  date.timezone = "Asia/Tehran"
```

gmdate also returns the same date (wrong date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime accepts unixtime in seconds, and you have it in milliseconds, so you must divide timestamp to 1000 before creating new DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $dt = new DateTime('@1410938094654');
```

gives: `November 6, 46680, 12:30 am`

```
 $dt = new DateTime('@1410938094');
```

gives `September 17, 2014, 7:14 am`

Convert it to seconds before using.